# How prove or disprove $\lfloor a^m\rfloor \neq \lfloor b^n\rfloor$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Question:**

> prove or disprove:
>   there exsit irrational
>    $a>1,b>1$ such that for all positive integers $m,n$,
>
> $$\lfloor a^m\rfloor \neq \lfloor b^n\rfloor$$

Now I can't prove this problem.

I know this following: 
$$a^m-\{a^m\}\neq b^n-\{b^n\}$$
since
$$a^m-b^n\neq \{a^m\}-\{b^n\}\in (-1,2)$$

I only have this idea. if one can take example, 
Thank you

Comment: I cannot completely follow: You want to find irrational $a,b$ so that $\lfloor a^m \rfloor \neq \lfloor b^n \rfloor$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb N$? What does your $\{\}$ notation mean?

Comment: “for any” is slightly murky language, I think. It could be read as “for some” or “for all” (or “for every”). I assume you mean the latter.

Comment: I have to post a mea culpa here.  I misread the problem, thinking that it asked for multiples of the irrational numbers rather than powers.  Thanks to Bill Dubuque for pointing this out to me.  I am going to withdraw my answer.  Apologies for my mistake.

Comment: Aargh, I can't delete an accepted answer.  If OP wants to unaccept it, than I will delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested to look at information on Beatty sequences and Rayleigh's Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence#Rayleigh_theorem

Comment: Is you answer meant to imply that you are certain that the result follows by the linked theorem, or, rather, that you *guess* that the theorem might be useful for this problem?

Comment: I would say that the link points you to information that solves the problem.

Comment: If you know a way to uee the theorem to give a complete proof, then please provide further details. Otherwise the answer reads like "maybe this will help, maybe not...".

Comment: @BillD After studying your comment and taking another look, I see that I misread the problem.  I thought it asked for multiples of the irrational numbers rather than powers.  I plan to post a comment to the question and withdraw my answer.  Thanks for helping me notice the mistake I made.